# Can a patent be applied for a scheme or product, that uses available techniques, to satisfy a specific purpose?

Tags: patentability, uspto, us7298271

I came across an article stating that the co-founder of Molo rewards has sued Google for allegedly infringing US Patent No. 7,298,271([Link to the patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US7298271)). On looking into the patent, it is clear that, the patent holder uses a RFID tag for reward points. Is it possible to get a patent for a scheme that uses existing technologies to satisfy one purpose ? If yes, under what category(like design) should I apply such a patent ?

Claim 1 of that patent:

> A method of providing awards comprising:
>
> (a) placing one or more electronic data storage elements containing directions to an award processing center at one or more locations;
>
> (b) providing participants in an awards program with electronic data storage element readers;
>
> (c) reading said directions to said award processing center from said electronic data storage element with said electronic data storage element reader;
>
> (d) utilizing said directions to access said award processing center;
>
> (e) identifying said participant; and
>
> (f) providing an award to said participant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most inventions use a collection of known elements put together in a unique way to achieve some functional result. Patents can be awarded for new uses of old things.

When one applies for a patent there is no need to state a "category".

Comment: I have an idea that is widely used in gaming industry, which I thought of incorporating into music industry. Can I patent application this ?

Comment: It depends on the details. There is a concept that a reference is not prior art if it in a "non-analogus" field and doesn't address the same problem. But there is no answer with out a lot of details and a search.